# Is the many-worlds interpretation less ill-defined than the Copenhagen interpretation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations, measurement-problem

In my understanding, the Copenhagen interpretation is ill-defined in the following way. The interpretation says that wavefunctions collapse when a measurement is performed. But the Copenhagen interpretation has no definition of measurement, only circular reasoning. For example, one could say ‘information on the result of the measurement must be stored somewhere’. But then you must define what ‘information storage’ is. This seems to be impossible in simple, physical terms. Also, a ‘macroscopic’ measurement consists of a large number of ‘microscopic’ fundamental interactions. Which one of these interactions is actually the measurement? The Copenhagen interpretation does not answer this and treats it as a black box.
Because of this lack of clear definitions, there are a lot of potential experiments where we do not know what the outcome would be; because we do not know whether the experiment constitutes a measurement or not. This is opposed to the conciseness of other physical laws: for example, we know exactly what the gravitational force is between two objects, if we know their respective masses. This is a simple, mathematical formula. But there is no simple criterion that says ‘this is a measurement, and this is not’.

In the many-worlds interpretation, there is no such thing as ‘measurement’. Therefore, does the many-worlds interpretation perfectly describe all potential experiments for which the Copenhagen interpretation is too vague? Or is there a corresponding component of the many-worlds interpretation which is ill-defined?

Comment: Well, it is an interpretation and up to now, there are no experiments which yield contradicting experimental results - hence the name *interpretation*. Same holds for MWI and any other interpretation. "Nature" does not care how you think about the world.

Comment: "because we do not know whether the experiment constitutes a measurement or not" - there are no such cases in practice.

Comment: 'In the many-worlds interpretation, there is no such thing as ‘measurement’'. Then this is not a physical theory at all, because measurements is what we do, and what QM came from. If a theory says that when you measure something, it does not matter because in another branch of the multiverse you measured something else, that theory is not about the physics of our world - it is just a sterile metaphysical speculation, and if taken seriously it even denies the very foundation of science, namely experimentation.

Comment: @StéphaneRollandin there is measurement in MWI, it is just not a fundamental non-definable concept as in Copenhagen.

Comment: I've voted to re-open this question. While foundations of quantum mechanics are controversial and somewhat taboo I think they are legitimate physics questions that have research-based answers that can even include citations. This answers to this question will need to deal heavily in foundations of quantum mechanics, but they need not be opinion based.

Answer (score 6):

I am not an expert on this issue, but I suppose to be quite familiar with  foundational aspects of Quantum Theory.

My honest opinion is that the MWI not only is equivalent to the standard interpretation regarding observations, but (up to now)  it does not add any further *physically testable* knowledge to the subject. If one is content with some metaphysical argument in addition to testable facts  it may have some sense, otherwise it is useless.

As far as I am concerned I do not need it and I feel it as a useless complication, though I think that the standard interpretation seems to be incomplete regarding the change of state process during measurements. Much more interesting approaches are the various attempts relying on decoherence.

Answer (score 2):

The Many-Worlds interpretation has one big problem: there is no clear way to incorporate the [Born rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Born_rule) into it. And the Born rule is what we are interested in when considering practical experiments.

In other words, MWI perfectly describes the universe as a whole, but how to get the exact empiric probabilities from it is unclear.

MWI does not contradict the Born rule, but it is not derivable from MWI. There were attempts to include the Born riule in MWI, which lead to different interpretations of their own (such as frequentist MWI).

Others argue that this is not a problem of MWI because a similar uncertainty arives in other contexts, where divided mind is involved, such as biology. Consider the following experiment: your brain is divided in two and then each half is inserted in new body and regenerated. Then one of the resulting people is given a billion dollars while the other is killed. Does the game worth it? What if the brain is divided not in half but unevenly? What's the probability that you would find yourself as the one to be killed after the experiment?

Comment: How about the results of actual experiments? Does the MWI give more actual predictions?

Comment: @Riemann the predictions of all quantum interpretations are the same. Otherwise they would be called theories rather than interpretations.

Comment: Ok so the answer to my question is ‘no’.

Comment: @Riemann if you are looking for a better defined interpretation, take a look at Bohmian mechanics. It is completely deterministic, has no collapse, particles move on trajectories rather than "smoothed" in space, no distinguished observer, etc. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Broglie%E2%80%93Bohm_theory (it is often called "theory" for historical reasons, but it is an interpretation as any other).

Comment: MWI is a qualitative rationalization of collapse. But no experiment can test it. It is a response to the so-called incompleteness of the Born rule.

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: my definition of the word “interpretation” in the context of quantum mechanics is any proposed solution to the measurement problem. Under this definition, two interpretations of quantum mechanics can make different physical predictions. Some define the word “interpretation” in a way that means two interpretations CANNOT make different predictions. If you are one of those people you may need to replace the word “interpretation” by “theory” in a few places in this answer.

Physicists don’t like to think about the mind/subjective experience/consciousness. But I argue that to fully consider the measurement problem and to even understand why it is a problem it is necessary to do so. Indeed, without subjective experience we have no grounds to claim there is anything strange about Schrödinger’s cat or Wigner’s friend.

Physicists don’t like to think about the mind, and possibly rightly so.  Nonetheless, I would say many physicists probably implicitly hold a dualist perspective on the mind which says that mental states of a mind are correlated (perhaps 1:1) with physical states of the body and brain.

The problem with quantum mechanics, for this point of view, is that under pure unitary dynamics (like in the Everettian, or many worlds as some like to call it, interpretation), quantum mechanics predicts cats and humans and their brains are described by highly entangled superpositions with the environment.

In my made up experiment “Schrodingers grad student” there is a human student that puts an electron in a 50-50 superposition of spin up and down. The student decides to measure it, but before measuring it they resolve to get pizza for lunch south of campus if they see spin down and a burrito north of campus if they see spin up. Unitary quantum mechanics (Everettian) predicts a physical state at the end of this experiment which has terms corresponding to the student being on both the north and south sides of campus and eating a pizza and burrito at the same time.

This is a nightmare for the naive dualist approach to the mind body problem. How can such a physical state, which simultaneously describes two radically different physical states of a human brain, be one to one with some mental state for that same human’s brain?

Copenhagen brow beats this problem into submission by stating, without physical evidence or clarity that it simply does not happen. The physical state collapses before such a philosophical abomination can arise. It is the equivalent of “nature abhors a vacuum” but instead “nature abhors a macroscopic superposition”*.

Finally to address the question in the OP. Is the Everettian interpretation I’ll-defined? Physically, no. Physically it is perfectly well defined. Physical states are described by mathematical states in Hilbert space and they evolve in time unitarily. BUT with respect to the mind body problem, the Everettian interpretation is unfortunately incredibly Ill-defined. The Everettian interpretation is the only one that states that Schrodingers grad student is indeed in two places at once eating two meals at once, but it makes zero philosophical commitment as to the student’s mental state during that time**, but the naive dualist 1:1 correspondence between physical and mental states must be wrong. This is how the Everettian interpretation is ill-defined. Sometimes you will read detractors phrase this by saying “the Many-worlds interpretation makes no predictions at all!”

Some physicists and philosophers have attempted to talk about, in the context of the Everettian interpretation, how mental states might be related to states like Schrodinger’s grad student, but I haven’t read a satisfactory solution yet. Nonetheless, I very much think it’s a fruitful direction for possibly solving the measurement problem worth pursuing just like I think putting experimental bounds on objective collapse theories is worth pursuing.

*Note that some objective collapse theories do a better job of specify when exactly collapse happens for a particular physical system than old school Copenhagen. These theories make predictions that are in principle measurably different than unitary QM but, for all experiments so far, the results are consistent with no collapse. Scientists will continue to make more and more impressive superpositions to better constrain the parameters of these theories.

**except perhaps that the student’s mind stressed out regardless!

Comment: This is a good answer, but I do not see where in the text your disclaimer is useful. It seems you never call a theory an interpretation in the text.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that the Many Worlds interpretation is more complete than the Copehnhagen one. All that Copenhagen tells you is what the problem is. The Copenhagen interpretation does not propose any solution.

In this sense, I would say the Copenhagen interpretation **anticipates** a completion of quantum mechanics. It is agnostic toward any specific completion.
Some of the completions can be Many Worlds, Relational QM, Gravitational Collapse, etc. The Copenhagen interpretation is compatible with **all of these completions**. All that Copenhagen interpretation is saying is that there **appears** to be a collapse upon measurement. All of the completions are in agreement with this. The completions just provide a specific mathematical description of what happens at measurement, like decoherence in Many Worlds, or non-linear Schrodinger equation in Gravitational collapse.

Comment: I’m glad someone is telling it like it is

Comment: I don’t see how Copenhagen is compatible with many worlds. If implementing a large many body unitary as well as its inverse is possible then many worlds and Copenhagen make different predictions for Wigner’s friend type experiments.

Comment: Gravitational Collapse is an objective collapse theory, thus not compatible with standard quantum mechanics.

Comment: @Jagerber48 if those experiments (like uploading a mind into quantum computer) would be practical, Copenhagen interpretation would be simply out of its domain there because it would be unclear what the observer is. It simply would be non-applicable.

Comment: -1 for including objective collapse theory that uses a modified Schroedinger's equation as a "completion" of Copenhagen interpretation. It is not compatible with standard quantum mechanis.

Comment: @Anixx Quantum Mechanics, combined with the Copenhagen interpretation, is not a mathematically precise theory. All it says is that there appears to be a collapse upon measurement. Objective Collapse agrees with this because it is supposed to reproduce Copenhagen for the currently accessible experiments. Objective collapse is a mathematically precise theory. It is meaningless to say that a precise theory contradicts an imprecise theory, because the latter theory is vague. All we can say is that objective collapse is compatible with Copenhagen in its vaguely defined domain of validity.

Comment: If you modify the Schroedinger equation, you diverge from standard quantum mechanics regardless of interpretation. You create a new theory.

Comment: @RyderRude Mathematics studies the properties of objects that exist only in the human imagination. These are not the same as the physical objects we model with mathematics. Physical objects obey their own rules, though. Copenhagen is a physically precise theory: no experiment has ever contradicted it. It appears that mathematical precision is only feasible in mathematics. There is no reason to expect anything else.

Comment: @JohnDoty I generally agree but not in this context. Copenhagen does not tell you how to draw the line between measurement devices and quantum systems. It is an incomplete and imprecise theory.

Comment: @RyderRude For what experiment is it imprecise? For it to be physically incomplete, there would have to be an experiment whose result it cannot address: I know of know such experiment.